# Get image dimensions from url path

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I am trying to load the dimensions of an image from url. So far I've tried using `GraphicsMagick` but it gives me `ENOENT` error.

Here's the code so far I've written.

```
var gm = require('gm');

...

gm(img.attribs.src).size(function (err, size) {
      if (!err) {
            if( size.width>200 && size.height>200)
            {
                console.log('Save this image');
            }
      }
});
```

Where `img.attribs.src` contains the `url source path` of the image.

**Update**

value of `img.attribs.src`

http://rack.1.mshcdn.com/assets/header_logo.v2-30574d105ad07318345ec8f1a85a3efa.png

Comment: What is the value of that string?

Comment: It wants a file path, not a URL.

Comment: I know @SLaks, but I want to perform the operation using a `URL`. You've any idea how to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [this](https://www.npmjs.org/package/imagesize) library to perform the operation successfully.

Answer (score 25):

https://github.com/nodeca/probe-image-size it does exactly you asked about, without heavy dependencies. Also, it downloads only necessary peace of files.

Example:

```
var probe = require('probe-image-size');

probe('http://example.com/image.jpg', function (err, result) {
  console.log(result);
  // => {
  //      width: xx,
  //      height: yy,
  //      type: 'jpg',
  //      mime: 'image/jpeg',
  //      wUnits: 'px',
  //      hUnits: 'px'
  //    }
});
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of this package.

Comment: 4,679 people (in the last month) can't be wrong! https://www.npmjs.com/package/probe-image-size

Comment: 705kb seems quite heavy for me to be honest: https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=probe-image-size@5.0.0

Comment: Just a heads-up the package is down to 340kB now and works like a dream! Thanks @Vitaly!

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is to download the file first. The easiest way is to use [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module. The cool thing is that both `request` and `gm` can use [streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html). The only thing you need to remember when working with streams and gm's identify commands (like size, format, etc) you need to set `bufferStream` option to `true`. More info [here](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm#streams).

```
var gm = require('gm');
var request = require('request');
var url = "http://strabo.com/gallery/albums/wallpaper/foo_wallpaper.sized.jpg";

var stream = request(url);
gm(stream, './img.jpg').size({ bufferStream: true }, function (err, size) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    console.log(size);
});
```

You could also download file on disk (using request as well) an then use `gm` as normal.

Answer (score 0):

You need the image-size NPM, this work fine at my end hope work at your

```
var sizeOf = require('image-size');
sizeOf('/images/'+adsImage, function (err, dimensions) {
        var imgwidth= dimensions.width;
        var imgheight= dimensions.height;
        console.log(imgheight +" = = = =  "+imgwidth)
  if( imgwidth>200 && imgheight>200)
        {
            console.log('Save this image');
        }


});
```

Comment: do you want to load image from URL sizeOf('http://www.example.com/image.png'... yes it may work,,i didnt try this

Comment: there is different method to use URL Image see page https://www.npmjs.org/package/image-size